# My regexp is not working

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to extract the error_name, Severity and Occurrences.
Here is the snippet of my report:

```
error_name: xxxxxxxxxx
Severity: Warning Occurrence: 2 
error_name2:xxxxxxxxxxx. 
Severity: Warning Occurrence: 16 
error_name3:xxxxxxxxxxxxx 
Severity: Warning Occurrence: 15
```

I am trying

```
while { [ gets $fp line ] >= 0 } {
    if { [ regexp {^([^:\s]):.+^Severity:\s+Warning\s+Occurrence:\s+\d+} $line match errName count] } {
        puts $errName
        puts $count
        incr errCount $count
}
```

But it does not write anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this:

```
set fid [open filename r]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    foreach {match label value} [regexp -inline -all {(\w+):\s*(\S*)} $line] {
        switch -exact -- $label {
            Severity   {set sev $value}
            Occurrence {set count $value}
            default    {set err $label}
        }
    }
    if {[info exists err] && [info exists sev] && [info exists count]} {
        puts $err
        puts $count
        incr errCount $count
        unset err count sev
    }
}
puts $errCount
```

```
error_name
2
error_name2
16
error_name3
15
33
```

Comment: You might want to add `close $fid` at the end :-)

Comment: Can you please explain it bit for my understanding.Thanks !

Comment: I read the file line-by-line. For every line, I look for all the occurrences of the pattern "word characters (letters, numbers, underscore) followed by a colon and optional whitespace, followed by any non-whitespace characters". Depending on the word before the colon I set a variable. Once all the variables have been populated, I perform the print and incr. I have to look for the presence of the variables because it takes more then 1 line to populate them.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this in a procedure and put in  table format as result but it gives nothing

Comment: I am putting my code in 2 comments.Its not letting me put in One

Comment: proc get_summary { Infile } {


set run_summary_file  [ glob $Infile/summary.rpt ]

set fp [ open $run_summary_file   "r" ]
    while { [ gets $fp line ]!= -1 } {
    foreach {match label value} [regexp -inline -all {(\w+):\s*(\S*)} $line] {
     switch -exact -- $label {
      Severity   {set sev $value}
      Occurrence {set count $value}
      default    {set err $label}
       }
  lappend pack_stats [ list $err $sev $count] 
     }
     return $pack_stats
}

Comment: set run_time_stats [ get_summary [ lindex $argv 0 ]  ]
          table_styler
     puts " \<table id=\"customers\" style=\"margin-bottom:10px;\" \> "
      puts "\<th\>  Rule \<\/th\>"
       puts "\<th\>  Severity   \<\/th\>"
       puts "\<th\>  Occurrence  \<\/th\>"
       puts "\<\/tr\>"

Comment: foreach k $run_time_stats {
                  set st [ lindex $k 0 ]
            set st_type [ lindex $k 1 ]
            set st_count [lindex $k 2]
            set BGCOLOR #FFFFFF 
            puts " \<tr\> \<td\> $st \<\/\> \<td bgcolor=\"$BGCOLOR\" \> $st \<\/td\> "
            puts "\<td\>$st_type \<\/td\>  \"                        
          puts "\<td\>  $st_count  \<\/td\> "
                       puts "\<\/tr\>"}

   puts " \<\/table\> "

Answer (score 0):

If you can hold the entire file in memory at once (depends on how big it is relative to how much memory you've got) then you can use a piece of clever RE trickery to pick everything out:

```
# Load the whole file into $data
set f [open $filename]
set data [read $f]
close $f

# Store the RE in its own variable for clarity
set RE {^(\w+):.*\nSeverity: +(\w+) +Occurrence: +(\d+)$}
foreach {- name severity occur} [regexp -all -inline -line $RE $data] {
    # Do something with each thing found
    puts "$name - $severity - $occur"
}
```

OK, now to explain. The key is that we're parsing the whole string at once, but we're using the `-line` option so that `^` and `$` become line-anchors and `.` won't match a newline. Apart from that, the `-all -inline` does what it says: returns a list of everything found, matches and submatches. We then iterate over that with `foreach` (the `-` is an odd variable name, but it's convenient for a “dummy discard”). This keeps the majority of the complicated string parsing in the RE engine rather than trying to do stuff in script.

You'll get better performance if you can constrain the start of the RE better than “word starting at line start” (as you can stop parsing a line sooner and continue to the next one) but if that's what your data is, that's what your data is.